# How to remove a variable from hiveconf

Tags: hadoop, hive

I set a variable in `hive` using the set command:

```
set a = value;
```

and I can use `${hiveconf:a}` to retrieve the value of a, namely `value`.
However, I couldn't find the way to delete this variable `a` from the hiveconf.
I tried

```
set a = ;
```

but when I use `set -v` to look at all the defined hiveconf properties and variables, it gives `a=`, the variable a is still there although it does not have a value.

Is there a way to remove this variable `a` from hiveconf?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, but why do you need to?

Comment: same question, though variables value can be reassigned, if new value is required. or exit from hive and login again

Comment: I thought deleting the variable is the best way to remove the value in it and at the same time free up the space to store it.

Comment: And I don't want it to appear with no value after I have done with it. However, it seems the variable would be removed from hiveconf if I exit hive and restart the hive session after some time.

Comment: So now I think may be it suffices setting the variable to no value. Anyway, thanks.